# Microsoft Text Driver or Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: oledb, jet, text-driver

In my application i have to read data from a CSV file. I want to use Microsoft Text Driver or Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.

I am confused between the two. Which one should i opt for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are more or less the same thing in that [they both use Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187670)

However, one is for [OLE DB and one for ODBC](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile), you might like to read [OLE DB for the ODBC Programmer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810892.aspx)